# Increment duplicates in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file like this:

```
20001 
17001
17001
53001
90001 
90001
90001
```

and I'm trying to modify $1 by adding one to it when it's a duplicate entry, so the output will be like this:

```
20001 
17001
17002
53001
90001 
90002
90003
```

Comment: Do the numbers have sufficient numerical distance that incrementing them doesn't lead to unwanted new duplicates? For example, if the original file had an additional line `90003` after your three occurences of `90001`, what should happen? A related question is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/598634/377345), btw.

Comment: no i don't have this case because that 1 in the end of each number is index

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
awk '{$1+=seen[$1]++} 1' file
```

Add post-incremented hash value to current value of $1 before printing.

The above will produce duplicate numbers when values are close together, such as the sequence 2,2,3 – the output is 2,3,3. A loop can be used to make that 2,3,4:

```
awk '{while (c[$1]) {$1 += c[$1] += c[$1+c[$1]]} c[$1]++} 1'
```

Array `c` stores the offset by which $1 is to be increased (like `seen` in the first example). Instead of increasing $1 only by the offset for that unique value, it's also increased by the offset from the next value until a new previously unseen $1 has been reached.

Comment: So much better than mine (now deleted). Or to process numbers wherever they are in the input: `perl -pe 's/\d+/$& + $seen{$&}++/ge' file`

Answer (score 3):

A variation on [@guest's answer](/a/600037) that guards against duplicate on output by incrementing the number as long as it's already been output before:

```
awk '{while ($1 in c) $1 += c[$1]++; c[$1]++; print}' file
```

Or the same in `perl`, processing numbers wherever they are in the input:

```
perl -pe 's{\d+}{
            $i = $&;
            while (defined($c{$i})) {$i += $c{$i}++}
            $c{$i}++;
            $i
          }ge' file
```

On an input like:

```
1
1
1
5
5
10
10
1
1
1
```

They give:

```
1
2
3
5
6
10
11
4
7
8
```

Comment: c[$1]++ : can you please explain the meaning of this and how to use it ?

Comment: How about `while (c[$1]) {$1 += c[$1] += c[$1+c[$1]] } c[$1]++`? Provides a speed up in some cases (was ~32x faster to deduplicate `shuf -r -i1-100 -n100000`).

Comment: @guest, again, so much better than mine. If you add that to your answer, I'll delete mine (again).